# Exchange 2013 Mailbox Move

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2013

I just installed Exchange 2013 on a domain with pre-existing Exchange 2007 SP3.

I'm trying to move a mailbox from the Exchange 2007 mailbox server to the new 2013 mailbox server. I created a Migration Batch for this via Exchange Administration Console, but get this error:

> Error: MigrationPermanentException: Active Directory property
>   'homeMDB' is not writeable on recipient 'mydomain.local/Domain
>   Users/User'. --> Active Directory property 'homeMDB' is not writeable
>   on recipient 'mydomain.local/Domain Users/User'.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add rights to Exchange Trusted Subsystem on the AD account.

Answer (score 0):

In AD users and computer we had to proper gate the rights on the mailbox, as the account we were using to migrate did not have permissions to carry out the migrate - even though they where and org admin.

http://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-active-directory-property-%E2%80%8Ehomemdb%E2%80%8E-writeable-recipient/

Comment: Can you review your answer and check what you are trying to say. Do you mean propagate?  And can you clarify what type of admin the account is